# SQL: Designing tables for storing agendas/schedule

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm trying to create a weekly (Monday - Sunday) schedule/agenda, similar to Google Calendar, using mySQL where users are able to fill out and display a schedule for what tasks they have at some day during some hour interval. For example a user task could store in the schedule as

Username | Day | Time | Task

Jimbob, Tuesday, 13:00, Eat super delicious spaghetti.

I'm wondering what is the best way to design the tables?

I could create a table for every day of the week, or have one big table that will store info for any day of the week. But what if I have a million users, would one big table be a performance issue?

Also, for the field of the tables I was planning to make one row store only one task for each hour, but I could also store all the tasks for each hour of the day. The latter could result in a lot of null values and take up more memory, but if the users fill out a lot of the calendar it seems like it could reduce a lot of rows, and redundant username entries. It also makes it easier to print out the schedule. Any thoughts?

Username | Hour | Task|

or

Username | 12am  |Task1 | 1am | Task2 | 2am ....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, imo, would be to have two tables: one for **users** and one for **tasks**.

Users would have a user ID, a username plus whatever else.

Tasks would have the date and time, the description of the task, a task ID and the user ID of the user whose task it is. You shouldn't make a table storing each day of the week since you can just query the dates of the tasks. This is how you should design the tables. The actual calendar and the queries should be done in PHP or whatever you want to use for it.